# Natural/Human Ordering String (Case Class with String)

Tags: scala

Currently I have a case class which has a Text field with the following contents:

```
    2 AT 30%
    2 AT 40%
    2 AT 50%
    5 AT 30%
    5 AT 40%
    5 AT 50%
   10 AT 30%
   10 AT 40%
   11 AT 30%
   12 AT 30%
```

Currently they are unordered so that 5 AT will be before 2 AT and so on.. is there a easy way to order them naturally or do I need to have something like that:

```
object ExtraCostOrdering extends Ordering[[ExtraCost] {


  override def compare(x: List[ExtraCost], y: List[ExtraCost]): Int = {

  }
}
```

And how do I do that correctly?

It should sort naturally so that
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 and not 11, 12, 2, 3, 4
Mostly text fields with numbers sorting is wrong.

Edit: Sometimes the List could contain Strings without any number at all so

```
    5 AT 50%
   10 AT 30%
   10 AT 40%
   I'm a String
```

is valid, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK a natural sort order isn't built into Scala.  However, you can simulate it easily by converting to integer types:

Given the following definitions...

```
def asNatural(row: String) = row.split(" ").head.toInt

val myList = List("5 AT 30%","12 AT 30%", "2 AT 40%", "5 AT 50%", "5 AT 40%")
```

...you can use `sortBy` to do a natural sort.

```
scala> myList.sortBy(asNatural)
res2: List[String] = List(2 AT 40%, 5 AT 30%, 5 AT 50%, 5 AT 40%, 12 AT 30%)
```

Of course, the above would fail if you have any poorly formatted strings coming in.  The following is slightly more 'production-ready', and will put all badly formatted strings to the end:

```
import scala.util.Try

def asNatural(row: String) =
  row.split(" ").headOption
                .flatMap{ head => Try(head.toInt).toOption }
                .getOrElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

Comment: That could work as long as my List[String] isn't mixed with Strings that won't contain any number at all. I have sometimes the list could also contain a plain string. But still your solution is great

Comment: Thanks - I added some example error processing.  Though you would probably be better off filtering out badly formatted lines entirely.

Comment: Thanks for all of this, In other languages I had a regex for that, which was really odd, but your solution is great and fast, however I splitted the list so that I doesn't need your "badly-formatted" solution, thanks.

Comment: 'Fraid I have to go now, but if the percentage values also need natural sort order (ie: 5% or 100% is possible)  the easiest way would be to use a regex to extract all the numbers in the string into a tuple of ints, and then sort on that.

Answer (score -2):

Since the ordering you want is standard you could just do something like:

```
val sorted: List[ExtraCost] = unsorted.sortWith((a,b) => a.textField > b.textField)
```

Comment: that's not a natural sort order.